# Why do I get an unauthorized error when deploy?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, github, devops

I am trying to ./deploy.sh from GitHub to my instance and unfortunately I receive an "unauthorized" error, can someone help me with it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGmXK.png)